# how to check if js file is downloaded on client end

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have experienced a weird problem with javascript.

The problem page uses some jQuery code to collect data and it does input checking validation. If the validation is true, it posts to the server. Some of our users reported (10% or maybe a lot less), they could not submit on the website.

We talked with one of the users who had the problem, and were even more confused afterwards.

Tester's PC:  XP, IE8, FireFox

The first time he used IE and the JavaScript validation did not fire, he was NOT able to submit data to server neither, because the validation was set to be false by default.
(it is supposed to have a error message showing up if the validation is false)

Afterwards he tested with F.F. (F.F. worked straight away).

Coming back to IE again, the validation script started working and the submit was again successful.

So, after all the tester don't have problem any more, and couldn't replicate neither.

I am wondering if there is any software or program may stop the js file from downloading properly? 
Because the page is also hosted in a i-frame in another website, that is why i thinking some antivirus may think this is a across-domain threat and stopped the posting working.

If so how can i do a check to ensure all the required js files are downloaded before user doing a submit?

What else should i look into, since the problem happens on client end only, with no server-end validation yet.

@drachenstern: thanks for the edit

Comment: Progressive enhancement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that there is some delay in loading the javascript on the client sde. anti-Virus "Internet secutiry" products (may) do a lot of checks.

It is highly possible that the internet security product scans a call, and then decides "ok, this is safe" and then the javascript file is downloaded. There *might* be a delay in this.

How to avoid the situation?

1. Don't tie your form submit to javascript. Let it happen always, with or without javascript. If javascript is ready the user will have a good experience (immediate validation). If it is not yet ready, the user will still be able to do the submit, do the validation and throw error messages the "traditional" way - by refreshing the page
2. Make the user wait till the javascript is loaded. You can have a small "loading" icon somewhere in the page to tell the user he has to wait. The user can enter the data, but can't submit yet. In the background, keep checking whether the javascript is loaded (`setTimeout` and checking for a specific variable). Once it is loaded, you can use javascript validations
3. A combination of the two: Allow non-javascript submit till you know that javascript is loaded. Once done, use javascript validations.

Answer (score 1):

You could disable the submit button, enable it only after jQuery is fully loaded and executed.

For example:

`<input type="submit" disabled />`

then, in your Javascript,

```
$(function () {
   $('input:submit').attr('disabled', false);
});
```

However, be advised that

1. User will not be able to submit
   anything on a browser that doesn't
   support Javascript
2. You should not
   depend on Javascript to verify the
   user content; always validate the
   data again on the server-side.

Comment: At the first point: to get around this just use javascript to disable the submit in the first place.

Comment: How would you know the javascript that disable the control being loaded or not?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest at first that you should always validate everything on the server. The only reason to validate on the client is to make the response to the user faster on bad inputs.

Additionally, to ensure that each file is downloaded and processed, you could always put a global var in each file, then check them in the document proper to see if each variable has been found. It's a crude back but it would work.

You didn't specify what version of IE the user was using, but the problem of the file not being loaded right away in IE sounds normal behavior to me, however quirky. I've run into that many times, and the only solution is a ctrl-F5 for me. I don't know what else to say there. It would be WONDERFUL if we could always have every browser respond the same, but we can't, so we go on. Also, what OS were they doing all this testing on? And What browser do you test on?

What behavior do you see in IE? If you're using IE8 or later, you'll have debug tools for sure, and you could always use FirebugLite to debug your pages in IE without using the IE tools. Then you could see what the page is doing in IE. Perhaps it's throwing a javascript parsing error? Are there any icons on the window chrome in IE that would give a tipoff?

But I think that if you're trying to fix the second paragraph, you're doing it wrong if you're relying on the javascript to process the validations. But I'm just one guy.

Comment: i think its ideal to validate at all 3 levels; client side, server side, and db constraints.

Comment: @MattBriggs ~ I agree, but the only reason to validate on the client is to enhance the process for the user and give immediate feedback. It is always so easily bypassed as to be merely a convenience.

Comment: the problem is, it stopped in client-end level, data was NOT submitted to server-end at all